# Call dynamic data in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to populate a value depending on the user role.

There are two ways to do this:

1. Add 600 lines in functions.PHP with then statements, (if user role=1 echo 1..... if user role=600 echo 600)

OR

2. Add a new meta value in the SQL database for the user upon registration and request this value from the data base.

**I think the second option is more logical** (unless the first option will bring a faster loading speed?)

Can anyone advice how can I request a parameter from a database in-line with the current user.

[image]

Comment: Not 100% sure I know what you are asking, but the best I can tell, are you trying to do:  `$val = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'portal_number');` from https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/  and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this help you.

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = $user->ID;
$get_portal_number = get_user_meta($user_id, 'portal_number', true);
print_r($get_portal_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the usage would depend on how you need to hook into that data but if its just in the functions file something like this would work.

```php
$user = wp_get_current_user(); // Gives you the current user
$roles = ( array ) $user->roles; // Gives you an array of their roles
```

At this could you could use in_array() to check for a specific user role and then display the meta data.

```php
if( in_array( 'role', $roles ) ) {
    echo get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'portal_number', true ); 
}
```